# Can't open Acrobat Reader in 64-bit Mint / Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, 64-bit, linux-mint, adobe-reader

After installing Adobe Reader 9, I receive the following error message when trying to run Adobe Reader.

```
/opt/Adobe/Reader9/Reader/intellinux/bin/acroread
error while loading shared libraries: libgdk_pixbuf_xlib-2.0.so.0
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Note that I had to run it from the console to see this error message. Running Adobe Reader from the desktop shortcut doesn't do anything; the application simply doesn't open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this, you need to install the 32-bit libraries in order for Adobe Reader to function correctly on a 64-bit system:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Or alternatively, if that doesn't work, try:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-multiarch
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer. Please also accept it so the thread can be marked as solved.

Comment: Will accept it as soon as I can; there's the 2 day limit before I can accept it as the answer.